# Loading a Combobox with a DataSet and Loading a Default Value

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a Windows Form application in C# and am sort of translating it from and asp.net forms application. I'm running into a difference I can't seem to get an answer on. I have loaded a combobox with items from a dataset but I would like the first item to say Select... or something like that rather than just show the first item from the dataset. In asp.net, I would just say

```
ddSelected.Items.Insert(0, "Select...");
```

But here I get an error: Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.

How can I do this in C# for Windows Forms?

Comment: just add the item to the underlying collection used as a DataSource. I must also mention that winforms is a dinosaur technology and if I were you, I'd rather do all new projects in either WPF or any other XAML-based technology.

Answer (score 1):

This solution may point you in the right direction, but it all depends on exactly what your `DataSource` object type is.

Imagine a scenario such as this:

```
    BindingList<string> myList = new BindingList<string>();
    myList.Add("Mark");
    myList.Add("Joe");
    myList.Add("Kelly");
    myList.Add("Susan");
    comboBox1.DataSource = myList;
```

All you would have to do is update your myList and the `ComboBox` items will update:

```
    myList.Insert(0, "Select...");
```

Note that this will work seamlessly with a [`BindingList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) because it implements [`IRaiseItemChangedEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.IRaiseItemChangedEvents.aspx).

If your underlying `DataSource` is an object such as an `ArrayList`, then in order to "Refresh" the `ComboBox` items, you would need to do something like:

```
    comboBox1.DataSource = null;
    comboBox1.DataSource = myList;
```

This is because the `ArrayList` class doesn't inherently raise events to notify any bound controls that the collection has changed.

1. Update your underlying datasource.
2. **If necessary,** update your `ComboBox` `Datasource` property by setting it `null` and back to your underlying datasource.